# What's the minimum transaction with monero?

Tags: transactions

What's the minimum transaction with monero. Can I send for example $0.01 in XMR to another person?

Answer (score 2):

You can send someone as little as 1 piconero (0.000000000001 XMR). In this case, the tx fee you'll pay will of course be more than your recipient amount.

So,

> What's the minimum transaction with monero?

The minimum output amount is 1 piconero and the minimum total tx amount is that plus the minimum tx fee (paid to miners to include the tx in a block).

> Can I send for example $0.01 in XMR to another person?

Yes.

Comment: What's the minimum amount of Monero that will result in the tx fee being the same as the money being spent?